# Flattening of nested tuples

Tags: python, tuples, flatten

Can you flatten a tuple such as this:

```
(42, (23, (22, (17, []))))
```

To become one tuple of all elements:

```
(42,23,22,17)
```

?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution using recursion:

```
tpl = (42, (23, (22, (17, []))))

def flatten(tpl):
    if isinstance(tpl, (tuple, list)):
        for v in tpl:
            yield from flatten(v)
    else:
        yield tpl

print(tuple(flatten(tpl)))
```

Prints:

```
(42, 23, 22, 17)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! Could you explain how this works? I don’t get this line: „if isinstance(tpl, (tuple, list)):“. Is the „tuple“ here just the first value, so 42 in the first run?

Comment: @PeterPefi No, in `(42, (23, (22, (17, []))))` you have many tuples: `(42, (23, (22, (17, []))))`, `(23, (22, (17, [])))`, `(22, (17, []))`, `(17, [])` and one list: `[]`. `isinstance(tpl, (tuple, list))` just tests if variable `tpl` is of type `tuple` or `list`

Comment: Ah okay, so you can add as many types into an isinstance query as you want.